# basic Radius of convergence question

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series

> $$\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{1}}+\frac{(x+2)^2}{\sqrt{2}}+...$$

I am asked to find the Radius of convergence how do I approach this?

Answer (score 0):

For every $x$, $\lim _n { (x+n)^n\over \sqrt n }=+\infty$, so you series of functions converges nowhere.
Proof. $f_n(x)= { (x+n)^n\over \sqrt n }= \exp  ({n \ln(n+x)-1/2\ln n} )$. So $x$ being fixed, $\ln f_n(x) =n \ln(n)+o(n)$.

Furthermore your series of function is not en entire series so "radius of convergence" has no meaning.

Answer (score 0):

In the same spirit as Thomas'answer, assuming an entire series, consider  $$S=\sum_{i=1}^\infty u_i \qquad , \qquad u_i= \frac{(x+i)^i}{\sqrt{i}}$$ So,$$\frac{u_{i+1}}{u_i}=\sqrt{\frac{i}{i+1}} \, \frac{(x+i+1)^{i+1}}{(x+i)^{i}}$$ $$\log\Big(\frac{u_{i+1}}{u_i}\Big)=(i+1) \log (x+i+1)-i \log (x+i)+\log \left(\sqrt{\frac{i}{i+1}}\right)$$ Developing as Taylor series for infinitely large values of $i$ leads to$$\log\Big(\frac{u_{i+1}}{u_i}\Big)=1+\log(i)
   +\frac{\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{1}{12}}{i^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{i^3}\right)$$ which makes $$\frac{u_{i+1}}{u_i}=e i+\frac{e
   \left(\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{1}{12}\right)}{i}+O\left(\frac{1}{i^2}\right)$$ from which you can conclude.